# making the "unanswered tags" section useful

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, sorting

I want the ability to quickly find a question I can answer. To speed up that process, I want to first filter to "C#" *OR* "Design-Patterns". Those are two broad categories where I have some chance of answering the question. However, those have many sub-categories (aka, tags commonly used with them) such as "ASP.NET" for example. Well, I despise ASP.NET I don't want to answer any questions about that. Essentially, once I've selected my several broad categories, I want to start filtering items out. If I click on the "Unanswered" button, there appears an "Unanswered Tags" section on the right. I want to select a few of those to keep and then whittle away at the rest of them such that I remove questions with tags that I don't want to deal with. When I click on a tag there it makes it required. From the same list I would like the ability to make a tag be "required to be absent".

Comment: What did you find when researching for the subject here on Meta?

Comment: Before I wrote this I read through many posts about the (un)manageability of the "Unanswered" tab and the sort orders available there. It seems to be a common problem, especially as the number of unanswered questions increases over time.

Comment: +1, I've also been puzzled by the inability to easily search for answerable questions. There's an awful lot of historic stuff in there so specialized nobody will ever be able to answer it, cluttering up currently existing filters too much.